# MySql code to get certain values

Tags: php, mysql

lets say I have this table in MySql data base.

> ```
> -------------------
> ID ||  Name  || Job
> -------------------
> 1  ||  Joe   || A
> 2  || Alice  || B
> 3  || John   || A
> ```

I need code that selects the values Joe and John because they have similar jobs and store the values in PHP variables, lets say `$i1 = Joe` and `$i2 = John`, please bear in mind that i have tables that have rows in hundred's of rows, so the `$i` can go up to hundreds.

Is this doable ?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very basic `MySQL`/`PHP` problem... Please show us your attempts up to this point.

Comment: 'similar jobs' as in Job 'A'? If this is the case just use a select statement.

Comment: I think you are looking for an array.  You should be able to find help here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Dont you have concept of arrays in php?

Comment: do you want all cases where two or more people have the same job ?

Comment: @Dagon : No , i want all cases where the Job = A

Comment: @brbcoding : I have no PHP programming background, i only know the basics, but obviously not enough to create this code. Thanks

Comment: then its a basic select `SELECT * FROM foo where job="A"`

Comment: @Dagon , yeah but how can I assign the values to the variables ?

Comment: there are more than a million basic php\mysql tutorials that cover this.

Comment: @Dagon Please guide me, Time is money.

Comment: you don't want a guide you want some one to write it for you, well go hire someone.

Comment: @Dagon any one in mind ?
im available at naser.yosef@gmail.com

Comment: my company charges me out at $250 an hour.

Comment: @Dagon I don't pay by Hour, I only pay by Code.

Comment: This is not what Stack Overflow is for. We're here to help you fix problems in your code, not as a substitute for knowing how to program by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple function to retrieve all the information in an array:

```
    function getStatuts(){  
           $sql = "SELECT Id,Name,Job FROM yourTable "; 
           $items = mysqli_query($sql); 

           while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($items)) {
               $array[$obj->id]['id'] = $obj->id;
               $array[$obj->id]['level'] = $obj->level;
               $array[$obj->id]['maxlines'] = $obj->maxlines;
        } 
        return $array;
    }

    echo '<pre>';
       print_r(getStatuts());
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Why use deprecated **`mysql_*`** functions?

Comment: @brbcoding He gets what he paid for.